# How to access a Vuex base state from a module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, token, vuex, vuex-modules

I successfully made a group in Vuex, but how do I access from the group to the base/non group state? In this case I want to access a user token from state in the base/non group state from product group.

This is my product group

```
const product = {
  state: () => ({
    product: [

    ]
  }),
  mutations: {
    retreiveProduct(state,product){
      state.product = product
    },
  },
  actions: {
    retreiveProduct(context){
      axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.state.token
      axios.get('/products')
        .then(response=>{
          context.commit('retreiveProduct',response.data)
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
    },
  },
  getters: {

  }
}
```

There is an error when getting the token from "context.state.token" in code above

and this is my user token code

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    product
  },
  state:{
    token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
    filter: 'all',
  },
})
```

If u see, I have declared a variable token and filled it with `access_token`. Can I call this variable from product group, or do I have to create another token variable in product group ?

Or do I have to make the other group retain the token ?

Can this be solved by namespace?

Comment: You can pass token as param inside action, so then you can call this.$store.dispatch('retreiveProduct', {product, token});

Comment: In this case I recommend to use interceptors to pass token for each request, or you don't need to store token in store when it is already in localStorage. In actions you also have access to localStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the action is in a Vuex module, and the state you're accessing is in the Vuex store root instead of the module's state, you need to access `rootState` from the `context` object instead of `state`:

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + context.rootState.token
```

The `context` object has:

- `state`
- `rootState`
- `getters`
- `rootGetters`
- `commit`
- `dispatch`

Comment: one more thing, after i login in router i redirect to /productall and data json was there, but when i reload /productall data json is empty, respone is empty, in product component i there is created() for retrieved product, what is wrong in my code ?

Comment: You should post a new question for this because it is about something else, and to give others a chance to answer too